# how to make a string variable with several line by a loop

Tags: string, matlab, loops

I need to write a string variable in several lines for example as bellow:

```
a = 1, b = 2, c = 3     
a = 0, b = 5, c = 1    
a = 4, b = 2, c = 0    
a = 8, b = 7, c = 3    
a = 3, b = 0, c = 8    
a = 2, b = 9, c = 3    
...    
a = 1, b = 5, c = 5
```

and save it in a text file.

I have a matrix containing 3 columns of a, b and c. What is an issue is definition of the string. What simply comes to mind but is absolutely wrong is as follows, I just wrote this to explain my problem better:

```
for i = 1:100
s(i) = (['a = ',num2str(A(i,1)),'b = ',num2str(A(2,1)),'c = ',num2str(A(2,1))]);
end
```

How can I generate such text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save this matrix with:

```
    A = round(abs(10*randn(100,3)));             %generation of random matrix

    fid = fopen('data.txt','w');                 %creation of the file data.txt, w stand for writing
    fprintf(fid,'a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n',...
A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3));                           %write the text
    fclose(fid);                                 %close the file
```

Comment: You code has the same problem of the one posted by @randomGuy.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `dlmwrite` function to write the strings in a `.txt` file as follows:

```
dlmwrite('my_output_file.txt',sprintf('a = %i, b = %i, c = %i\n',A'),'delimiter','')
```

Notice, you should use the `transpose` of the input matrix A otherwhise the values wll be get "column-wise".

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the only answer here that solves the OP's problem. +1.

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf('a = %i, b = %i, c = %i\n',A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3))`

will generate a string of what you would like to save in your text file.

Comment: Notice, your codeactually writes the values of the input matrix "column-wise, that is it assigns to `a`, `b` and `c` first the values in the first column of A, then the ones in the second and so on, while in the question is stated that the values of `a`, `b` and `c` are defined by column.